# Float table to bottom of page in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007

Is it possible to float a table to the bottom of a page in Word 2007?

I am making a template for revisable documents for work (specs, routines etc) and I want the front page to contain the document title, and a table of revisions. I want to float this table to the bottom of the page. So as I add rows to it, it grows upwards towards the title (which is at top of page, and not middle.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a page break on your title page, then

1. Insert your table after the title (I'd insert it on a new line so that it doesn't have the title's style)
2. Right click the table and select “Table Properties...”.
3. In the “Table” tab, “Text wrapping”, select “Around”, which makes the nearby “Positioning...” button active.
4. In the “Positioning” dialog, select vertical position as “Bottom” relative to “Margin”.

When adding to the table, it should now grow upward.

Comment: Ta.  I learned a few things myself while working it out.

Comment: Still works in Word 2013.

Comment: I found that the last row always runs over to the next page though. What's going on?

Comment: @fatuhoku Does it work for you on a new blank document?  Either way, it's probably better to open a new question rather than try to solve it in comments.

Comment: Still works in Word 2019

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with inserting a table that covered the whole page. One column, two rows. Bottom row aligns to bottom.

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. No 'proper' way to float / align a table at the bottom as far as I can see, your best bet would be to put the table in the footer (not ideal I know, but does achieve the appearance you want)