# Float table top page margin with caption above table

Tags: microsoft-word, caption

I have table that I want to "float" at the top of a page. Following the logic from this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/167807) and setting the vertical position as “Top” relative to “Margin” helps me achieve the position of the table. However, the problem now is the table caption that was originally above the table has now been pushed to below the table.

How can I keep the caption above the table that is newly positioned at the top relative to the page margin?

Comment: Put the caption inside the table.

Comment: @RichMichaels Ha, nice and easy! Thanks